# How to filter elements in one list by a property value not present in elements in another list?

Tags: kotlin, collections

I have the following code snippet

```
val cachedNews = listOf(News(9, "https://009"), News(8, "https://234"), News(7, "https://345"))
val freshNews = listOf(News(1, "https://123"), News(2, "https://234"), News(3, "https://345"))

val result = freshNews.filter {fresh -> filter(cachedNews, fresh)}

private fun filter(cached: List<News>, fresh: News): Boolean {
cached.forEach { cachedItem ->
    if (cachedItem.url == fresh.url) return true
}
return false }
```

When the code runs if `cachedItem.url == fresh.url` the list is filtered and the result is a list where the `urls` of the two lists are identical. However when i reverse equality like so `cachedItem.url != fresh.url` the list is not filtered at all. The sequence of execution changes.

When using the `==` sign, the first item of `freshNews` is compared with the first Item  of `cachedNews` after that the secondItem of `freshNews` is compared with secondItem of `cachedNews` and so on.

When I use the `!=` sign the all items of `freshNews` are compared against only the firstItem of `cachedNews` ??

Am I missing something or is my code just wrong?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I don't understand your explanation of what reversing the equality is. Maybe you can show that complete code so we can contrast the two situations. Your `filter` function can be simplified to `return cached.any { it.url == fresh.url }`

Comment: I'm trying to find the intersection of the two lists where the URLs are not equal

Comment: You only want to compare items that are at the same index in each list?

Comment: Yes I want to do that. Then if the items have different URLs I want to create a separate list with the different items only.

Comment: I modified the answer because I think the first version was too complex, assuming you only need the values from `freshNews`.

Comment: Yes. I only need the values from `freshNews`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what the specific problem is because your approach is quite confusing. Your custom `filter` function is actually more like a `contains` function.

What might be useful is to:

1. Extract the cached URLs to a set
2. Filter the new results by URLs that are not in the set.

```
fun main() {
    val cachedNews = listOf(News(9, "https://009"), News(8, "https://234"), News(7, "https://345"))
    val freshNews = listOf(News(1, "https://123"), News(2, "https://234"), News(3, "https://345"))

    val cachedUrls = cachedNews.map { it.url }.toSet()
    val result = freshNews.filterNot { cachedUrls.contains(it.url) }
    println(result)
}
```

Result:

```
[News(id=1, url=https://123)]
```

Comment: The problem was that I wanted to compare all the elements of the two lists specifically the URLs.   Then filter one list according to the differences. Makes sense ?

Comment: Is the `toSet()` call still necessary here ?

Comment: "according to the differences" means, you want the elements of `freshNews` whose urls are not present in `cachedNews`, right? Basically you're looking for elements with unseen urls. `toSet()` is not necessary, it's for efficiency. `contains` on a list is an `O(n)` operation, but on a set it's `O(1)`.

Comment: Yes, that's what I want. You summed it up quite nicely.  Didn't know contains on a set is constant time. Man, you are good. So is writing code like above a result of experience or it comes natural (you are one of the prodigies)?

Comment: Haha thanks for the complement, but it's pretty basic stuff. Answering lots of questions on Stack Overflow helps .